# string.search | number of hits

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm searching for a number in a string, using the .search string method:

```
var myString = "20 fur bar 50";
alert(myString.search(/\d/);
```

This returns the position of the first number: 0.
How can I get the position of the second number?
Is there a way to find out how many hits there are?

Answer (score 2):

Use `match` instead and the `g` (global) flag.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJkDB/).

If you don't want to match the digits individually, change it to `\d+`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emhSu/).

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I was searching for.

Comment: was he originally asking for positions? :)

Comment: @naveen It looks like it but then the OP said this is exactly what they needed :)

Comment: +1: yep thats true indeed :). was more curious if its possible to do the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

How can I get the position of the second number?

> myString.indexOf(myString.match(/\d/g)[1])

Is there a way to find out how many hits there are?

> myString.match(/\d/g).length

Of course, I have hardcoded index 1 above, you have to do proper checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `exec`:

```
var myString = "20 fur bar 50";
var numberPositions = [];
var numberRe = /\d+/g;
for (var match; (match = numberRe.exec(myString));) {
  numberPositions.push(
      [numberRe.lastIndex - match[0].length, numberRe.lastIndex]);
}
```

then `numberPositions` is an array of start (inclusive), end (exclusive) pairs:

```
[[0,2],[11,13]]
```

[0,2] is the range of characters (end-exclusive) for `20` and [11,13] is the corresponding range for `50`.

The regexp used there is `/\d+/` instead of `/\d/` so that instead of getting a separate range for `2` and `0` you get one range for the whole integer.